# dojo mobile with phonegap doesn't work properly

Tags: html, cordova, dojo

I start write application using phonegap and dojo in Eclipse. Phonegap, without dojo work properly on android emulator and in chrome with ripple addon. Problem is when I added dojo to project. I use `phonegap 2.7.0` and `dojo 1.9.0`. 
I was using: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-mobappdev1/ tutorial to setup this.

How I setup dojo:

[image]

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>PhoneGap</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/dojo/dojox/mobile/themes/android/android.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/dojo/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="funkcja.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          dojo.require("dojox.mobile.parser");
          dojo.require("dojox.mobile");
          dojo.require("dojox.mobile.app");
          dojo.require("dojox.mobile.Button");
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" id="site" selected="true">
            <h1 dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading">Index</h1>
            <div>
                <input dojoType="dojox.mobile.Button" type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Button" onclick="loguj()"/> 
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

In emulator I get a blank screen.

In chrome using ripple I get just html without dojo scripts. Scripts are include. In console I get an errors:

```
Console was cleared ripple.js:37
Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Gray. Hot.) ripple.js:37
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u Insertion.js:1
GET http://localhost/config.xml 404 (Not Found) ripple.js:50
cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.) ripple.js:37
GET http://localhost/libs/dojo/dojo/fx/Toggler.js 404 (Not Found) ripple.js:50
Error {src: "dojoLoader", info: "xhrFailed"} dojo.js:15
GET http://localhost/cordova_plugins.json 404 (Not Found) ripple.js:50
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < cordova-2.7.0.js:6816
GET http://localhost/libs/dojo/dojo/resources/blank.gif 404 (Not Found) app.js:15
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova-2.7.0.js:6672
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady cordova-2.7.0.js:6665
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady cordova-2.7.0.js:6665
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady cordova-2.7.0.js:6665
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova-2.7.0.js:6672
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady cordova-2.7.0.js:6665
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady cordova-2.7.0.js:6665
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady cordova-2.7.0.js:6665
```

Answer (score 0):

Dojo tries to load his js files, but can't. I think this answer may work for you too:

[PhoneGap / Cordova 1.6 and dojo 1.7.2 AMD works from web, not from local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209558/phonegap-cordova-1-6-and-dojo-1-7-2-amd-works-from-web-not-from-local)

> Set the djConfig of dojo.js to djConfig="async:false,parseOnLoad:true"
>   **AND** load cordova.js before dojo.js !

If it doesnt work & you want to start developing, try to use dojo.js from the web.

Comment: did you try to load cordova before dojo

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `cordova_plugins.json` file into `www` with `{}` inside.

Alternatively, you can comment out lines `6395->6415` from `cordova-2.7.0.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial on [IBM Website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-mobappdev1/) and it also did not work.

To make it work I had to do the following:

1. Remove `djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"`
2. Replace

   dojo.require("dojox.mobile.parser");
   dojo.require("dojox.mobile");
   dojo.require("dojox.mobile.app");
   dojo.require("dojox.mobile.Button");

with:

```
require(["dojox/mobile/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/app", "dojox/mobile/Button", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(parser) {
        parser.parse();
    }
);
```